# Parse XML in Lua (Freeswitch)

Tags: lua, xml-parsing, freeswitch

How to parse an xml file in lua while using it in Freeswitch?

I tried these projects:

https://github.com/manoelcampos/LuaXML

https://github.com/Cluain/Lua-Simple-XML-Parser

https://github.com/Phrogz/SLAXML

Here is the sample xml called back from the ASR module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result grammar="pvn_accept">
    <interpretation grammar="pvn_accept" confidence="100">
        <input mode="speech">accept</input>
    </interpretation>
</result>
```

They are all failing due to anonymous functions.

```
'<name>' expected near anonymous function lua
```

Is there an inbuilt support on Freeswitch to parse xml?

Note: The lua file stored as .m4

Comment: If Freeswitch is interfering with basic Lua functionality like creating anonymous functions, that's a much larger problem. You're unlikely to be able to run anything in such an environment. You first need to localize the actual error; find out if Freeswitch is the cause or if it's something you have done.

Comment: [Lua in Freeswitch](https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/src/mod/languages/mod_lua/lua) looks like it was not modified.  And I can not find error message you gave in FreeSwitch sources.

Comment: Can you paste the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out what's happening. It was due to storing the lua file with .m4 extension and format is an m4 keyword.

For example in https://github.com/Cluain/Lua-Simple-XML-Parser, we had to make this change:

```
  function XmlParser:ToXmlString(value)
        value = string.gsub(value, "&", "&amp;"); -- '&' -> "&amp;"
        value = string.gsub(value, "<", "&lt;"); -- '<' -> "&lt;"
        value = string.gsub(value, ">", "&gt;"); -- '>' -> "&gt;"
        value = string.gsub(value, "\"", "&quot;"); -- '"' -> "&quot;"
        value = string.gsub(value, "([^%w%&%;%p%\t% ])",
            function(c)
                return string.`format'("&#x%X;", string.byte(c))
            end);
        return value;
    end
```